# Widget HTML editing - Need Links to Open in New Page

Tags: html, widget

I have an HTML code for this ZipRecruiter Widget below. It seems to cause the links to open within the same frame, causing an error message on my website. I need the links to open to a new page altogether. I know the code to open to a new page is target="_blank">, but I can't figure out where to put this piece of code, or if this is possible to do at all with the code provided....

ZipRecruiter Widget code:

```
<a href="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs/affera-inc-87dfed24" id="jobs_widget_company_link">Job listings at Affera, Inc.</a><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs-widget/v1/a66da7e4/all?show_posted_days=0"></script><a href="https://www.ziprecruiter.com" id="jobs_widget_link_split">Provided by ZipRecruiter</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Place the `target="_blank"` after the URL.

I have added it in the code below for you, just copy and paste it.

```
<a href="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs/affera-inc-87dfed24" target="_blank" id="jobs_widget_company_link">Job listings at Affera, Inc.</a><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs-widget/v1/a66da7e4/all?show_posted_days=0"></script><a href="https://www.ziprecruiter.com" id="jobs_widget_link_split">Provided by ZipRecruiter</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried placing it there and the links are still trying to open on the same page and/or frame, according to the error I get on my site. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have two `<a href>`'s here. Try putting the `target="_blank`" in both of them.